# Backward difference in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, automation

How can I write backward difference in LaTeX?
 [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I do is use an empty math atom as the anchor for the pre-script.  I have to also (upon EDIT) add a `\strut`ed pre-superscript in order to push down the pre-subscript to the proper level as the post-subscript that later follows.

Or, as shown in the 2nd case, one can tighten the gap after the pre-subscript by manually adding a negative space `\!` to the end of the subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
{}_{k_0}^{\strut}\Delta_k^{(n)}
\]
\[
{}_{k_0\!}^{\strut}\Delta_k^{(n)} f(k) = \sum_{i=k_0}^k a_{i-k_0}^{(n)} f(k + k_0 - i)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `fouridx` package  gives slightly better spacing for the right exponent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{fouridx}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}%
  {}_{k₀\!}^{\strut}\Delta_k^{(n)} \\%
  \fourIdx{}{k₀}{(n)}{k}{\!Δ}
\end{gather*}%

\end{document}
```

[image]